# Asp.NetCore UserStore slow user retrieval from database context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I have a weird situation which I don't understand. While testing my API I noticed slow api queries which boils down to retrieving the user from the store (after login).

When I override the FindByIdAsync method in my UserStore I can see a delay of 500ms when retrieving the User from the DbContext.

```java
public override async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    ThrowIfDisposed();

    if (!int.TryParse(userId, out int id))
    {
        return null;
    }

    // This takes 500+ ms
    return Context.User.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
}
```

Now the weird thing is when I do the same in a controller it is fast.

For example:

```java
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    // This function will end up at the UserStore.FindByIdAsync (see above)
    // And takes 500+ ms
    User user = await signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(this.User);

    // This however is fast... (just using a sample id)
    context.User.Where(u => u.Id == 1896);

    return Ok(await context.Session.Where(s => s.UserId == user.Id).ToListAsync());
}
```

I do not understand why this is. I tried swapping the two functions to see whether it was a warmup thing or something. But that is not the case..

I also looking in the source code from the UserStore and the Context there should be the same as the context in the Controller

I inject the context in the controller:

```java
public SessionController(SignInManager<User> signInManager, MyDbContext context)
{
    this.signInManager = signInManager;
    // This is the same context as in the UserStore since the context is also injected in the  UserStore
    this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ConfigureAwait(false) at the await call
User user = await signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(this.User).ConfigureAwait(false);
await context.Session.Where(s => s.UserId == user.Id).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)

Comment: if possible, add an explanation why this code works. that will help the question poster understand why they should use this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the call is actually not execute to the database **until** I do .ToListAsync() or .SingleAsync().

That is why I do not see the delay. Also, the problem is somewhere else since I connected to my database through ssh port forwarding. I believe that is why it is actually that slow. I was misguided by the fact one executes fast and the other not (because what I said above)